# Horizontally enlarged hexagon with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to draw some nodes for a diagram, but I'm failing to produce a simple horizontally enlarged hexagon.

If I use `regular polygon` (from shapes.geometric), I cannot enlarge it (first figure in image below). I tried to set `shape aspect` just to no avail.

A workaround I found in the pgfmanual, is to use the `chamfered rectangle` (from shapes.misc), but then we must be cautious about the balance between `xsep` and how much text there is inside the rectangle (second and third figure in image below).

This is the code that produces the figures below:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, draw] (reg) {Regular node};
  \node[chamfered rectangle, chamfered rectangle xsep=2cm, draw] (chamf) [right=of reg] {Enlarged node};
  \node[chamfered rectangle, chamfered rectangle xsep=1cm, text width=2cm, draw] (chamfB) [below=of chamf] {Enlarged node with many lines that flow down};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Figures]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To scale the hexagon horizontally, you can use the `xscale` option; you can add the text using the  `label=center:<text>` option to the hexagon node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum width=2cm,draw,label=center:some text] (reg1) at (0,0){};
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum width=1cm, xscale=3,draw,label=center:some text] (reg2) at (3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, but it also scales the polygon. I've just edited my question so that stays clear that I need to enlarge the polygon just in the X-axis.

Comment: @Nicolás: see my updated answer.

Comment: Obviously, there is an option to scale along the y axis also: `yscale`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `scale` to each node. Here is a version with and with the default of `scale=1` and `scale=1.3` appliled:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, draw,scale=1] (reg) {Regular node};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, draw,scale=1.3] (reg) {Regular node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you have an issue with adding multiple lines of text to the node then you need to specify the width of the text and an alignment with:

```
text width=2.4cm,align=center
```

This is independent of the scaling issue and yields:

[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, draw,scale=1,text width=2.4cm,align=center] (reg) {Enlarged node with many lines that flow down};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, draw,scale=1.3,text width=2.4cm,align=center] (reg) {Enlarged node with many lines that flow down};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer to manually decide where the line break should be, by adding a `\\`, then you do not need to specify `text width=2.4cm`. So use:

```
\node ... {Enlarged node \\ with many lines \\ that flow down}
```

Here is the full code for this:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, draw,scale=1,text width=2.4cm,align=center] (reg) {Enlarged node \\ with many lines \\ that flow down};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, draw,scale=1.3,align=center] (reg) {Enlarged node \\ with many lines \\ that flow down};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, but this is not what I need. I'm looking for a way to enlarge horizontally the hexagon, not scale it up or down.